# how to show li in two vertical parts(side by site like newspaper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so what I'm trying to do is to show ordered list in two separate parts.

```
<li>hi</li>  <li>hi</li>
<li>hi</li>  <li>hi</li>
<li>hi</li>  <li>hi</li>
<li>hi</li>  <li>hi</li>
<li>hi</li>  <li>hi</li>
```

How do I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title">Mywebsite <small>orderedlist</small></h2>
        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p><a href="#" class="image-shadow"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/qS86202.jpg" width="500" height="150" alt="" /></a></p>
            <p>
               <ol>
                  <li>a</li>
                  <li>b</li>
                  <li>c</li>
                  <li>d</li>
                  <li>d</li>
                  <li>e</li>
                  <li>f</li>
              </ol>
           </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4wbsvc2b/

Comment: use `display: inline-block` or `float` for `li` and `width: 50%`

Comment: Here is an article http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean [like this ?](https://jsfiddle.net/4wbsvc2b/2/)

```
ol { 
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make two ol blocks and float left or you can use the suggested column-count which I recommened. You do not need to put your ol blocks in divs they are block elements just like div is a block element. Also p is a block element so you do not need to put in in a div either.